# IIS 10 fails to parse .cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, iis-10

I am developing an mvc c# episerver website. The site is loaded on IIS 10/Win 10 wih a dedicated application pool etc. After I did some changes in the code and on the specific .cshtml that relates to a layout I receive the following error on all the pages that share that layout.

> The following file could not be rendered because its extension
>   ".cshtml" might not be supported:
>   "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/_Root.cshtml".
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The following file could
>   not be rendered because its extension ".cshtml" might not be
>   supported: "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/_Root.cshtml".
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

All the other pages with different Layouts work fine. Also if I load the website with visual studio iisexpress works fine.

Anyone has any idea why my IIS is freaking out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this](http://www.herlitz.nu/2016/11/28/episerver-10-upgrade-error-the-following-file-could-not-be-rendered-because-its-extension-.cshtml/) the solution is to clear the asp.net cache files

Delete the files inside the folders:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
> Files\
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
> Files\

Comment: I somehow failed to check this solution even though I stumbled upon it on my google results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a compilation error in your view.

For me it was a broken dependency which caused and a broken taghelper